# After installing SSL certificate firefox cannot open the website

Tags: ssl, firefox, https

I have installed a SSL certificate on my domain https://www.xn--reitve-ckb.si/

But now, when I open this website in FireFox (version 60.0.1, 64 bit) the website does not open, but rather an dialog opens (please check image):

[image]

All my other browsers (IE, Edge, Crome) are opening website just fine. Also my hosting provider can open the website without any problem with FireFox, but I cannot.

What could be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do is to clear browsing history and now it works:)